# Spring:Propagation.REQUIRED not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-3, spring-transactions

I am inserting records in a couple of tables namely `Dept` and `Emp`. If the `Dept` table is successfully created then only I want to insert records in `Emp` table. Also, if any of the insert in `Emp` fails, then I want to rollback all the transaction which includes both rollback from `Emp` as well as `Dept` tables.

I tried this using `Propagation.REQUIRED` as shown below:

**Java File**

```
public void saveEmployee(Employee empl){
    try {
        jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO EMP VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)",empl.getEmpId(),empl.getEmpName(),
                empl.getDeptId(),empl.getAge(),empl.getSex());
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void saveRecords(){
    saveDepartment(dept);
    saveEmployee(empl);     
}
```

**context.xml**

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">        
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

**Problem:**

Even if an insertion in `Emp` table fails, the `Dept` insertion is getting persisted which I don't want. I want to rollback everything.

Please suggest.

Comment: You're catching the exception...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is your catch block. Since the exception is catched the tx don't rollback.

You must throw the exception :

```
public void saveEmployee(Employee empl){
    try {
        jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO EMP VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)",empl.getEmpId(),empl.getEmpName(),
                empl.getDeptId(),empl.getAge(),empl.getSex());
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }

}
```

And by the way, the semantic of *Progation.Required* just means : create a new tx if it don't exists OR use an existing one if there is tx running.

---

Following your comment here is a suggestion to see the effect of NEW tx :

```
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void saveEmployee(Employee empl){
    try {
        jdbcTemplate.update("INSERT INTO EMP VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)",empl.getEmpId(),empl.getEmpName(),
                empl.getDeptId(),empl.getAge(),empl.getSex());
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }

}

@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void saveRecords(){
    saveDepartment(dept);
    try{
       saveEmployee(empl);
    }catch(Exception e){Logger.log("Fail to save emp !");}     
}
```

The key point to see the effect of REQUIRES_NEW is to catch the exception around saveEmployee. If you don't catch it : the exception will propagate in the other tx (the one started when entering saveRecords() ) and it will rollback too.

Comment: The above solution worked. Just for testing purpose, I added `@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` on top of the `saveEmployee` method to see how it works. My expectation was: `Dept` record will be saved and `Emp` record wont get saved since `NEW` will create a new transaction. But I am surprised to see the output: Neither `Dept` nor `Emp` record got saved. Did I missed anything? Please explain.

Comment: Why is the exception not thrown in this case? IS it because we dont have anything to rollback? Also, why did my piece of code did not worked? What difference does the try block makes while invoking the `saveEmployee` method? Please advice

Comment: @user182944 see my edited edit ;-) With this sample code I think that you will see that dept will be saved even when empl insert fail

Comment: yes now it works...but I am not able to understand why that try block makes this difference...can you please explain?

Comment: Thanks fr the explanation, it helped :)

Comment: Hi.. does this Traction Rollback only helps if the exception is thrown in DAO class while persisting Data? What if the user tries to throw an Exception when any logic fails in the Service Class? Does the previous transactions too gets rollbacked? Need help.

Comment: @AshfaqueRifaye if one tx rollback, the previous tx don't rollback. It really depends on when/where you start your tx. A tx may contains an arbitrary number of database operation, and at the end (of the tx) will ALWAYS either "commit" or "rollback". If an exception was thrown during the tx all database operations that where done since the beginning of the tx won't be executed (i.e. the transaction rollback), on the other hand if everything was fine during the tx, it should ends with a "commit" of all database operations than were executed during the tx.